# Correct syntax to html php conversion

Tags: php, html

I  have made a huge mistake. I wrote a long code inside only one php tag and now when I have to format it with a .css it makes me a huge pain to develop. I tried to convert it to php tags but I always get HTTP 500 error.

```
<?php
    $args = array('post_type' => 'menu', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post__in'  => $ids, 'post_status' => 'any', 'orderby' => 'post__in');
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                      if (is_page(538) ) {
                        echo get_the_title();
                        $levesek = get_field('levesek');
                        $leves_adag = get_field('leves_adag');
                        echo "<br>Levesek:<br>";
                       if($levesek) {
                            foreach ($levesek as $leves) {
                                setup_postdata($leves);
                                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $leves->ID ) ."<br>";
                            }
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

Comment: you are missing the three curly brackets in before wp_reset_postdata().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the three curly brackets in before wp_reset_postdata().

backup your code and replace with this.

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'menu', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post__in'  => $ids, 'post_status' => 'any', 'orderby' => 'post__in');

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        if (is_page(538) ) {
            echo get_the_title();
            $levesek = get_field('levesek');
            $leves_adag = get_field('leves_adag');
            echo "<br>Levesek:<br>";
            if($levesek) {
                foreach ($levesek as $leves) {
                    setup_postdata($leves);
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $leves->ID ) ."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: It's okay, I fixed it, my problem is to convert this whole think to <?php tags
Like `<?php echo "Text" ?>`